# RegEx for extracting part of HTML elements

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

so I'm trying to pull events from this website
https://www.oldmuseum.org/
using a regexp tester. It's working, but I also get receive events that are sold out.

This is the regular expression I'm trying to use.

```
summary-title-link">([^>]+(?!SOLD OUT))<
```

Produced output:

```
'An Evening with Sun Kil Moon'
'Amity Dry- Fortified'
'Teeny Tiny Stevies - SOLD OUT'
'Cine Retro '
```

I'm trying to not get the sold out event. I'm not sure how to fix this regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

If only the SOLD OUT text is undesired, we could add a simple right boundary next to that, something similar to:

```
 summary-title-link">(.+?)(?: - SOLD OUT)<
```

The first capturing group `$1` is our desired title link, followed by an optional  `- SOLD OUT`.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xSGVgY/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /summary-title-link">(.+?)(- SOLD OUT)?</gm;
const str = `<a href="/event/bpo29sept" class="summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - SOLD OUT</a>
<a href="/event/bpo29sept" class="summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - SOLD OUT</a>
<a href="/event/bpo29sept" class="summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - SOLD OUT</a>
<a href="/event/bpo29sept" class="summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - (Some other data)</a>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

If SOLD OUT elements are not fully desired, we can simply remove them using an expression similar to:

```
summary-title-link">(((?!SOLD OUT)[\s\S])*?)<\/
```

[image]

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UVTJnS/1)

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /summary-title-link">(((?!SOLD OUT)[\s\S])*?)<\//gm;
const str = `summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - (Some other data)</a>
summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - SOLD OUT</a>
summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - SOLD OUT</a>
summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - (Some other data)</a>
summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - SOLD OUT</a>
summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - (Some other data)</a>
summary-title-link">Brisbane Philharmonic Orchestra - (Some other data)</a>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just say I don't want `SOLD OUT` exists in my string.

```regex
summary-title-link">(((?!SOLD OUT).)+)<
```

following this pattern, we are saying any character which is not `SOLD OUT` ending with a `<`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffXHGE/1)**